# Export data from MS Project to Excel

Tags: export, microsoft-project, microsoft-excel

We are using MS Project 2003 and MS Excel 2007.

We would like to export task data from Project to Excel. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [office.microsoft.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/project-help/export-timephased-or-timescaled-project-data-to-excel-HP043007929.aspx):

> **Export timephased (or timescaled)
>   project data to Excel:**
>
> If you want to display timephased (or
>   timescaled) information in a Microsoft
>   Office Excel 2003 graph or chart, you
>   can export it using the Analyze
>   Timescaled Data Wizard.
>
> 1. On the View menu, click Gantt
> 2. If applicable, select the tasks you want to export.
> 3. On the View menu, point to Toolbars, and then click Analysis.
> 4. Click Analyze Timescaled Data in Excel.
> 5. Following the Analyze Timescaled Data Wizard instructions, click the
>      fields you want to export to Excel.
>
> To learn other ways to export data
>   from Project, see the related links in
>   the See Also box, which is visible
>   when you are connected to the
>   Internet.
>
> Notes:
>
> - Timescaled information is also known    as timephased information.
> - If you don't see any information    exported, then you may not have
>     specified which fields to use in the
>     wizard. Re-run the wizard and select
>     the fields you want to export in step 
>     2 of the wizard.
> - The wizard does not export resource    assignment information.

You may also want to check out this link: [Export Project data to another file format](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/project-help/export-project-data-to-another-file-format-HP043007930.aspx?CTT=1).